# how can I disable bootstrap modal on desktop and enable only for mobile/tablets?

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1wUh.png)

We have two user interface, one for desktop and one for mobile, when user gonna login via desktop, then the username input and username password fields will show, and when it turns into mobile view, then both fields will be hidden and the screen shows look like below;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlbD3.png)

the issue is this, when I try to log in and click on login button, the login will appear ok, but when I click on login via desktop, the modal will appear too, I want to move or display hidden login popup on desktop screen. please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle click event on the button and check whether are input fields visible or not. If not, then show modal programmatically by calling `$("#modal").modal('show')`

So as default, use your login form as regular form (dont use bootstrap modal) and in JS:

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function() {  //catch button click
     if ( !$("#username").is(":visible") ) { //is mobile version?
          event.preventDefault(); //dont send form
          $("#modal").modal('show'); //but instead, show modal
     }
});
```

Comment: No sir, i think you didn't understand my question yet, i want to remove or no want to show bootstrap login modal on web or desktop just.

Comment: @RajaHassan I do understand, I've edited original answer with code sample